How to check if user is entering only numbers
I'm trying to update my registration system. I want user entering his age, but I don't know how to check if user entered only numbers. I will give snippet of my code, where it doesn't work
my views.py:
def Registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        age = request.POST["age"]

        ...

        if username.isnumeric() == "True":
            messages.error(request, "Username can't be all number!")
            return redirect("/")
        if age.isnumeric() == "False":
            messages.error(request, "Age must be all numbers!")
            return redirect("/")
        
        ...

        messages.success(request, "Your account has been succesfully created")

        return redirect("/Login/")
    return render(request, "Registration.html")

my registration.html:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/solar/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

    <title> view tasks </title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">

        <h1>Registrate here</h1>
        <form action="/Registration/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for"username">Username</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Create a username (letter and numbers only)" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"age">Age</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"fname">First Name</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"lname">Last Name</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Enter your last name" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"email">Email</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"pass1">Password</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" placeholder="Create your password" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <label for"pass2">Confirm Password</label>
            <br>
            <input class="" type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm your password" Required>
            <br> <br>

            <button type"submit"> Registrate </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>

</html>

I tried researching functions that could solve my problem, but I didn't find anything, maybe didn't look enough. The problem isn't at raising errors, it worked on other ifs. The age.isnumeric() isn't working as I thought it would.

What does "it doesn't work" mean? And why not just use <input type="number" instead of "text"?

isnumeric() method returns True or False, as a boolean, not a String, hence you should remove the "" and have something like :
if username.isnumeric() == True:
# THE REST OF YOUR CODE 


I would do just if username.isnumeric():

This worked! Also how @Musty mentioned, i can make instead of  <input type="text"> i can do <input type="number"/>.

isnumeric() method in itself is boolean. you don't have to compare it like =='True' ( which is a string ). just use if username.isnumeric():. Also in your use case for checking non-negative integer values you can use isdigit().

You can update the input field in your registration.html from
<input class="" type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age" Required>

to
<input type="number" id="age" name="age" min="10" max="100" />

you can read more about it here

This coul be a good use case for django Form class, which provides you data validation.
from django import form

class UserDataForm(form.Form):

    age = form.IntegerField(
        label="Age",
        min_value=10,
        max_value=100,
        required=True)
    # validates age is an integer.

See the field description in official doc.
Add a field in your form class for each data to validate. Then your can use it in your function view
myform = UserDataForm(request.POST)
# parameter names must be the same as attributes of the form
if myform.is_valid():
    # your logic here

One step further is to use a ModelForm and a class based view (inheriting CreateView) :

Define your Model
Define your ModelForm and implement validation here (see validators if you want more control)
Simply inherit CreateView and provide your model and form classes. You may want to override form_valid and form_invalid methods.

